# Array formatting method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, syntax, format

Hi i'm trying to format and create this array:

```
Person[] persons = { person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6, person7, person8, person9, person10 };
// The aim is to form an array of the 5 strongest people's indices above
int[] arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices = new int[5]; 
for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++){
    int strength = persons[index].strength;

    for (int str : arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices){

       //something @ here ?

    }
}
```

So I'm trying to loop through 10 people, and the array `arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices` should be 5 of the strongest people's index (in order of strongest to weakest, i.e `array[0]` is the strongest person's index out of the 5, and `array[4]` is the weakest of the 5)

Question: How do I return arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices formatted as stated?

Comment: please post the executable code because persons array size we can't guess.

Comment: do you even have a question for this post?

Comment: Edited the main post, should be easier to read now

Comment: can you use List? or is this an assignment and have to stick to array?

Comment: interchangeable, but end result is array

Comment: cause you can  make a List of persons  which has a nice method .sort() which take a comparator that you can implement on field strenght.
Then sort it and go back to array

Comment: could you post an example? Kind of confused

Answer (score 0):

So this is my idea, tried it and it should work.
When I find a person that is stronger than any in the 'strongest' ArrayList I move all elements that come after it for one spot.

```
ArrayList<int> strongest = new ArrayList<int>();
strongest.append(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    int str = persons[i].strength;
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if(str > strongest[j]) {
            int temp = strongest[j];
            strongest[j] = str;
            str = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-

```
List<Person> p = Arrays.asList(person);

Collections.sort(p, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person a1, Persona2) {
        return a1.strenght.compareTo(a2.strenght); //im assuming strenght is a number
    }
});

person = p.toArray(new Person[0]);
```

now you have an ordered array of person from weakest to strongest

Comment: Thanks, was unaware of such a tool, is it that the number of persons I am looping through (50 currently not 500) is causing the massive delay upon execution or is it that this tool is slower?

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that returns an array of integers which represent the indices of the strongest persons.

```
public int[] findStrongestIndices(Person[] persons) {
    int[] arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int str = persons[j].strength;
            if (i == 0) {
                if (str > temp)
                    temp = str;
            }
            else {
                if (str > temp 
                        && str < persons[arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices[i - 1]].strength)
                    temp = str;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < persons.length; j++) {
            if (temp = persons[j].strength)
                arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices[i] = j;
                break;
        }
    }
    return arrayOfStrongestPeopleIndices;
}
```

I had to overhaul the code to keep up with the edits. This method will accept a "Person" array of any length and return an integer array with a length of 5.